# searchBarSearchButtonClicked is not being detected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have set up a search bar using the embed nav bar. The func searchBarSearchButtonClicked is not being detected. I'd like to make it so that when the user taps on the search bar, another function will be called. I've taken out some extraneous code not relevant to this question. What could be the issue?

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {  

var resultSearchController: UISearchController? = nil                       

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set up the search results table
    let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable

    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable

    let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Where would you like to go"
    navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
    searchBar.delegate = self

    resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true                                  
    }                              

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_: UISearchBar) {
    //  closeMapType()
    //  self.mapType.transform = .identity
    print("it worked")
  }                                                                      
}
```

Comment: Code seems fine did you tried in Device ? and pressing enter if in case of simulator

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work and the print function didn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below function will call when the user taps on the search bar :

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This will call when we click on the "Search" button in the keyboard

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_: UISearchBar)
```

Comment: Okay it worked! I also just realized that one of the functions I'm trying to call is in another class. How do I call the function from another class? Do I need to use an extension? or is it possible within the this FirstViewController class that I'm currently in

Comment: I figured it out with "FloatingActionButton().beginTracking(touch: UITouch, with: UIEvent?)" do you have any idea what I should put in UITouch or UIEvent?

Comment: @Vini App `searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_: UISearchBar)` being called when clicking the "Search" button in the keyboard" was the answer for me. Why doesn't Apple mention this in their docs? I couldn't find this info in any other sites. Thanks!